# ssh_connect: Library not initialized (LibSSH)

Tags: c++, compilation, static-linking, libssh

I have the following piece of code which I am trying to build statically, so I end up with a single executable.

```
#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1
   
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
   
#pragma comment(lib, "mbedcrypto.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "pthreadVSE3.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ssh.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    ssh_session my_ssh_session;
    int method, rc;
    int port = 22;
    const char* password;
    int verbosity = SSH_LOG_FUNCTIONS;
    //int stricthostcheck = 0;

    std::string host = "10.10.10.100";
    std::string user = "user";

    // Open session and set options
    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, host.c_str());
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, user.c_str());
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);

     // Connect to server
    rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        exit(-99);
    }
    
    // Authenticate ourselves
    password = "Password";
    rc = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, NULL, password);
    if (rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error authenticating with password: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        exit(-1);
    }

    ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
    ssh_

free(my_ssh_session);
}
```

I have installed the following libraries using VCPKG

```
libssh:x86-windows-static
zlib:x86-windows-static
openssh:x86-windows-static
```

I have manually linked the following include path, in the `C/C++` section of project properties on the `General` tab under `Additional include directories`

```
C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include
```

I have also under in the `Linker` section of project properties, also on its `General` tab, added an entry for Additional library directories

```
C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\lib
```

The additional libraries are linked in the code, using the following four lines of code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "mbedcrypto.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "pthreadVSE3.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ssh.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
```

I have also set the C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime option to Multi-Threaded (/MT)

When I run the program it compiles fine, creating a single executable. However, when I run the program, I get an error stating "ssh_connect:  Library not initialized"
[image]

[image]

This is day three of trying to get this to work, with no previous knowledge of how to compile applications. Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 days spent on guessing instead of reading [the manual](https://github.com/simonsj/libssh/blob/master/doc/threading.dox) - it's unbelievable. Almost on the top:

> - If libssh is statically linked, threading must be initialized by calling
>   `ssh_init()` before using any of libssh provided functions. This initialization
>   must be done outside of any threading context. Don't forget to call
>   `ssh_finalize()` to avoid memory leak

By the way, any examples of libbssh usage have calls to `ssh_init()` and `ssh_finalize()`. You can look at [the unit tests.](https://github.com/simonsj/libssh/tree/master/tests)

Comment: Thank you, trouble is I didn't know if I was doing the static linking correctly, so was looking for the wrong thing. All working now. Thanks